# Order array of associative arrays by sub-array existence of key

Tags: php, sorting

Sorry for the utterly bad title, I do not really know how to oneline this.

I have an array with this kind of structure

```
$users = [
    [
        "name" => "Marcos",
        "roles" => [
            "admin" => "2023-11-16T10:23:45Z",
            "reader" => "2023-11-16T10:24:23Z"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Roberto",
        "roles" => [
            "admin" => "2023-11-16T10:23:45Z",
        ]
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Jaime",
        "roles" => [
            "admin" => "2023-11-16T10:23:45Z",
            "writer" => "2023-11-16T10:24:23Z"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Xabier",
        "roles" => [
            "roles" => [
                "admin" => "2023-11-16T10:23:45Z",
                "writer" => "2023-11-16T10:24:23Z",
                "reader" => "2023-11-16T10:24:23Z"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

All users are admin if they appear in this array.

I would like to sort the users considering the roles they have, and increase step by step, role preference is preferred alphabetically:

- First admin
- Then admin + role1
- Then admin + role1 + role 2
- Then admin + role2
- and so on...

Comment: What you did tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: So far i used uasorting to try and achieve this, but apart from not getting it done I didn't feel i was doing the right thing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code there. Thanks

Comment: @Marcos'HaddocK'Pérez So `admin + reader` should come first OR `admin + writer`..?

Comment: @nice_dev If i could choose i'd take the next value by alphabetic order!

Comment: @Marcos'HaddocK'Pérez So can you add the order priority in your post?

Comment: @brombeer sorry, but I ain't have something helpful so far

Comment: @nice_dev updated

Comment: @Marcos'HaddocK'Pérez Can we re-order `admin + writer + reader` as `admin + reader + writer`? Also, the last row in your array has an additional `roles` level. I believe it's a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *role preference is preferred alphabetically*.

This tells us that we need to sort the keys of the `roles` array. We can do so by [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

> First admin

> Then admin + role1

> Then admin + role1 + role 2

> Then admin + role2

We will have to have a way to compare the `roles` keys one by one and return values accordingly in our custom callback function for [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

The hack for this to make our code more compact is to implode the keys of the `roles` array(after sorting) on a pipe symbol(`|`) or any other delimiter you like and pass it onto our [`strcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

foreach($users as &$u){
    ksort($u['roles']); // so that we don't sort this every time during comparison which is time consuming and not efficient.
}

usort($users, fn($a, $b) => strcmp(
                                implode("|", array_keys($a['roles'])), 
                                implode("|", array_keys($b['roles']))
                            )
    );

print_r($users);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/sRrvS)

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice approach, this fitted best and it looks quite optimum!

Comment: @Marcos'HaddocK'Pérez Glad to point you in the right direction.